# In how many ways can we seat 2 men and 2 women alternating among 12 chairs in a row?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

The following problem seemed interesting to me. I would like to verify whether my solution is correct.

So we have two men, $m_1$ and $m_2$, as well as two women, $w_1$ and $w_2$. Men and women must be seated in alternating order among a row of 12 chairs. Open chairs may be found between men and women.

I reason as follows: we can select any 4 chairs from the 12 such that order does not matter. Hence, we have $^{12}C_4$ where

$$ ^nC_r = \binom{n}{r} = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}.$$

Next, we can arrange among the tiles a pattern/order that fits the template $m,w,m,w,m$ (this template only has 4 tiles filled and just represent the possible ordering of men an women such that we are not choosing 5 tiles) where men have to fill 2 of the 3 spaces $^3P_2$ and women fill 2 of the 2 spaces $^2P_2$ such that order does not matter and where
$$ ^nP_r  = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!}.$$
We reason that we must choose 4 from the 12 tiles (order doesn't matter) AND 2 of the 3 positions for men (order matters) AND 2 of the 2 positions for women (order matters). This gives us a total of $^{12}C_4 \times {}^3P_2 \times {}^2P_2 = 5940 $ orderings. This problem can be extended/generalised to
$$ ^nC_{2m} \times {}^{m+1}P_{m} \times {}^{m}P_{m}  $$
where $n$ is the number of chairs, $m$ the number of men and/or women with the requirement that $2m \leq n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because if you don't fill the middle male position you get mwwm which is not alternating. I believe the correct answer would be to multiply $\binom{12}{4}$ by 8 (the men can be ordered in 2 ways, the women can be ordered in 2 ways and we need to choose if the men or women go first)

In general you would get

$$ \binom{n}{2m} \times 2 \times (m!)^2 $$

Comment: Neatly done  ! (+1)